# Create a table grid using a single repeat control in xpages

Tags: xpages

I would like to create a table with 4 columns and 4 or more rows (so 16 or more items per page) using a single repeat control. Is this possible at all? I have achieved the desired affect in the past using div tags and display in-line, but would like to know whether it's possible to achieve this using a table. When the code is generated by a repeat control, how could I tell it to create a new row when it reaches the 4th element?? Any ideas at all?

Comment: You could also use a datatable instead.

Comment: How would a datatable help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repeat control has facets for the header and footer that you can use to output the html tags required for the table header and footer like this...

```
<xp:this.facets>
<xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="header" escape="false">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
<th>Column 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer" escape="false">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
</tbody>
</table>]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:this.facets>
```

Then inside your repeat control you could repeat a single computed field which will output the html and cell contents for the table. use the Repeat Index variable to determine if the computed field control should include the `<tr>` or `</tr>` tags and make sure the control has been set to display contents as html.

Comment: Many thanks Declan - will give this a go and keep you posted.

Comment: Declan - I was just wondering, if I add a computed field, won't it create a span tag automatically around the content? Then I will have span tags around <tr> and </tr>

Comment: there is a property called disableOutputField that can be used to stop the span tags from being generated. It was added in 8.5.3 for exactly this purpose of being able to use them inside repeats in this manner.